# c++ saving struct into a file issue

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my function in c++ that saves a structure to a file. It appears to save everything correctly, when I open the file back up everything has been saved. But when I run the program again the loading file goes into an infinite loop for some reason, I am uncertain as to why this is happening. Any input would be welcome.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

struct account
{
    string acctNum;
    string name;
    float cBal;
    float sBal;
};

int menu();
char subMenu();
int loadCustomers(account[]);
void saveCusomers(account[], int);
int newCustomer(account[], int);
int deleteCustomer(account[], int);
int findCustomer(account[], int);
void deposit(account[], int);
void withdrawl(account[], int);
void balance(account[], int);
void bankBalance(account[], int);

int main()
{
    account acc[20];
    int selection;
    int numAcc = 0;

    numAcc = loadCustomers(acc);

    saveCusomers(acc, numAcc);

    return 0;
}



int loadCustomers(account acc[])
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int numCustomers = 0, i = 0;

    inFile.open("customer.dat");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "No customer file found." << endl;
    }

    else
    {   
        cout << "Customer file found..." << endl << endl;

        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, acc[i].acctNum, '#');
            getline(inFile, acc[i].name, '#');
            inFile >> acc[i].cBal;
            inFile.ignore();
            inFile >> acc[i].sBal;

            i++;
            numCustomers++;
        }

        cout << "Number of customers found in file: " << numCustomers << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return numCustomers;
}

void saveCusomers(account acc[], int numCustomers)
{
    ofstream outFile;

    outFile.open("customer.dat");

    for (int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++)
    {
        outFile << acc[i].acctNum;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].name;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].cBal;
        outFile << '#';
        outFile << acc[i].sBal;
        outFile << '#';
    }

    outFile.close();
}
```

I am not sure if I am saving it infinitely or why it loops infinitely, any comments would help.

Comment: I don't have the energy needed to debug your code at the moment, but I can tell you this much; this line: `while (!inFile.eof())` is almost (99.99% of the time) always wrong. You call `getline` *twice* after that check. Think about that for a moment.

Comment: Your data in the file is all in one line, each field *and* structure separated by the `'#'` character. You skip *some* of those separators when reading the file, but not all. I recommend using something else as a structure separator, like a newline, then the reading and parsing of the data could be made easier to handle errors, including a very easy fix for the problem pointed out by @EdS..

Comment: Since you are using getline, you will need to output an equivalent std::endl one the lines.

Comment: @cup: `getline` accepts a separator token, in this case, `#`.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing

```
while (!inFile.eof())
```

with

```
 while(getline(inFile, acc[i].acctNum, '#'))
```

and remove 
`getline(inFile, acc[i].acctNum, '#');` 
as first statement in you while

Comment: Changing that helped with the infinite loop issue, but for some reason my saving function loads a bunch of addresses for the function now, the first account loads fine then the next loads the addresses.

Comment: add inFile.ignore(); after inFile >> acc[i].sBal; too